# Insert into SQL Server timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, insert-into

I have `table1` and `table2` and I am inserting data into `table3` based on rows from tables 1 + 2. I need get evidence in to table 3 when was data insert.

**Table1**:

```
Column1
a
b
d
e
g
h
i
```

**Table2**:

```
Column1
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table3](column1)
    SELECT column1
    FROM [dbo].[table2]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
                      FROM [dbo].[table1]
                      WHERE column1 = column1);
```

Result:

**Table3**:

```
Column1  Column2
c
f
```

I need get in to exist table and exist column (`varchar(50)` or `timestamp`) any format of time which will show me time when was insert values in to table using my current script.

Example:

**Table3**:

```
Column1 Column2
c       4/4/2017 
f       4/4/2017
```

Few days later should table look like this :

**Table3**:

```
Column1 Column2
c       4/4/2017 
f       4/4/2017
x       5/4/2017  
y       6/4/2017
z       10/4/2019
```

Thanks for upgrade my script  for :

Something like :

```
INSERT INTO table3 (Column2) 
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: DO NOT EVER store datetime information in a varchar column. It is a horrible idea. We have a datetime datatype for this type of information. And forget about TIMESTAMP, it has nothing to do with times or dates. For the question at hand you could either add a not null constraint to the datetime column with a default of getdate() or provide the current time with getdate() in the insert statement.

Answer (score 3):

Just `ADD` one more column into table3 by `ALTER TABLE TABLE3 ADD COLUMN updated Datetime2 DEFAULT GETDATE()`

And just do the inserts as what you did, every time you insert a new row into table3, the last field `updated` will be populated with the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Add some Audit columns for the table like below

---

```
[StatusCode] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ConstraintName_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
[LastModifiedByUserId] [int] NULL ,
[LastModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
```